# LWJGL crashes on glReadPixels after a few frames

Tags: java, opengl, segmentation-fault, lwjgl, buffer-overflow

I'm using LWJGL to render a triangle to an offscreen framebuffer with renderbuffer. After rendering the scene, I read out the data from the renderbuffer to RAM using `glReadPixels`. The first few frames work great, but then the program crashes (SEGFAULT, or SIGABRT, ...).

What am I doing wrong here?

```
//Create memory buffer in RAM to copy frame from GPU to.
ByteBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(3*width*height);

while(true){
    // Set framebuffer, clear screen, render objects, wait for render to finish, ...
    ...

    //Read frame from GPU to RAM
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

    //Move cursor in buffer back to the begin and copy the contents to the java image
    buf.position(0);
    buf.get(imgBackingByteArray);

    //Use buffer
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `glReadPixels`, `ByteBuffer.get()`, or basically accessing ByteBuffer in any way, changes the current position of the pointer in the buffer.

What happens here is:

1. The position of the buffer is initially zero.
2. The call to `glReadPixels` copies the bytes from the GPU to the buffer, starting at the current position (`= 0`)
3. The current position gets changed to the amount of bytes that was written to the buffer.
4. `buf.position(0)` resets the position to 0.
5. `buf.get()` copies the bytes in the buffer to `imgBackingByteArray` **and changes the position to the amount of bytes that was read**
6. The next iteration of the loop tries to read bytes into the buffer, but the current position is at the end of the buffer and so a buffer overflow occurs. This triggers a crash.

Solution:

```
//Make sure we start writing to the buffer at offset 0
buf.position(0);
//Read frame from GPU to RAM
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

//Move cursor in buffer back to the begin and copy the contents to the java image
buf.position(0);
buf.get(imgBackingByteArray);
```